# Cannot add image into Form with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to post an image into a Form using Google Apps Script using the same code that it is in the [Google Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/image-item) and it doesn't work:

```
// Open a form by ID and add a new image item
var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
form.addImageItem()
    .setTitle('Google')
    .setHelpText('Google Logo') // The help text is the image description
    .setImage(img);
```

It used to work in the past, but now, if you try to execute this, it fails in the last line:

```
function myFunction(){
    var form = FormApp.openById('1fCraIkgem06Cu4M8EkbbwYi4uQL7S290Ev_-qLa_3xE');
    var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
    form.addImageItem()
        .setTitle('Google')
        .setHelpText('Google Logo') // The help text is the image description
        .setImage(img);
}
```

And the error...

> Datos no válidos al actualizar el formulario. (línea 7, archivo
>   "Encuestas") Cerrar

In english: *Invalid data when updating the form. (line 7, file...)*

It's very frustrating because I used to do this tons of times in the past and now it's not working. Does anybody has the same problem?

I have also tryied to take the image from GoogleDrive, but the result is always the same.

Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported bug. You can follow the progress at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135217119